# JSX React HTML5 Input Slider Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, slider, reactjs

I'm using React.JS for a build, and am building a range input slider with two choices for a component.

this is my code:

```
<input id="typeinp" type="range" min="0" max="5" value="3" step="1"/>
```

When I place it into my client side rendering component and try to toggle it it does not move at all. Testing it onto a JS/PHP build I have going on, it works fine.

Why does this not work in JSX/React.JS and what would be a suggested work around?

Thanks!

Comment: And what does this client side rendering component look like ?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

User interactions have no effect because an `<input>` with `value` prop is considered as **controlled**. It means that displayed value is controlled entirely by `render` function. So to actually update input value you should use the `onChange` event. Example:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {value: 3};
},
handleChange: function(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <input 
      id="typeinp" 
      type="range" 
      min="0" max="5" 
      value={this.state.value} 
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      step="1"/>
  );
}
```

You can also use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. In this case `<input>` is considered as **uncontrolled** and any user interactions are immediately reflected by element itself without invoking `render` function of your component.

More on this in official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. I ended up using constructor (ES6 syntax) and used a defaultvalue to make this happen. Thanks for the link to the official docs as well.

Comment: [!] You should initialize state in the constructor when using ES6 classes, and define the `getInitialState` method when using React.createClass.

Answer (score 17):

I think previous answers fix your problem. However, I'd say the solution doesn't need to involve React states.

The only reason behind your frozen input slider is that you've hardcoded its value to 3, as @Colin Whitmarsh suggests.

Simply, this works:

```
<input id="typeinp" type="range" min="0" max="5" defaultValue="3" step="1"/>
```

Now, you probably need its output to do something. You can use `onChange={this.handleChange}` as @xCrZx states in his answer. But inside `handleChange` you don't necessarily have to update your state. Depending on your logic, you could avoid increasing the complexity of your state and simply code your logic inside `handleChange`.

If you avoid updating the state, you'll probably save some renders and your performance will improve.

Answer (score 9):

I hope the above solutions might have resolved your issue, I have one simple approach using hooks.

```js
const RangeSlider = () => {

  const [rangeval, setRangeval] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="range" className="custom-range" min="199" max="3999" 
       onChange={(event) => setRangeval(event.target.value)} />
      <h4>The range value is {rangeval}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RangeSlider;
```

Comment: When we click "run code snippet", it shows a error message. This answer should be checked again.

Comment: It most likely doesn't work in the run code snippet, because it is jsx, and the emulator doesn't know how to work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
onInput() {
    var input = document.getElementById("typeinp");
    var currentVal = input.value;
    this.setState({
      value: currentVal
    })
}

<input id="typeinp" type="range" min="0" max="5" step="1" defaultValue="3" onInput={this.onInput.bind(this)}/>
```

I suggest changing value="3" to **defaultValue="3"**, otherwise I think value is hardcoded to "3" and may be difficult or impossible to change. The onInput function finds the value and adds it to state so the data can be passed to another component or function. There's likely a more elegant solution to your problem, but the above should work.

Comment: Thanks! The defaultvalue and state function did the trick. Although I did end up creating a constructor and assigning a default value to it as well

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for making form of multiple sliders or even one single slider with event handler passed
we can simply use HTML input of type Range 
[rc-slider](https://github.com/schrodinger/rc-slider) and [react-input-range](https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range) don't sent **event handler** `onChange` or `onAfterChange` they sends the slider's value Implicitly, so we can't handle form of sliders or create them on the fly.

[jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/okasha/zs61go1v/)

For more we can check [HTML input Range](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) and CSS provided by [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

```js
class SlidersExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      slidersLabels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
      sumOfCustomWeights: 0,
      slidersWeights: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const slidersLabels = this.state.slidersLabels;
    const slidersWeights = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slidersLabels.length; ++i)
      slidersWeights[slidersLabels[i]] = 0;
    this.setState({ slidersWeights });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.generateSliders()}
        <span> Total Weights: {this.state.sumOfCustomWeights} </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
  generateSliders() {
    const slidersLabels = this.state.slidersLabels;
    var sliders = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < slidersLabels.length; ++i) {
      sliders.push(
        <div style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
          <span style={{ fontSize: "16px", marginBottom: "6px" }}>
            {" "}
            {slidersLabels[i]} ({this.state.slidersWeights[slidersLabels[i]]})%
          </span>
          <input
            id={slidersLabels[i]}
            type="range"
            defaultValue="0"
            min="0"
            max="100"
            className="slider"
            onChange={this.handleSliderChange.bind(this)}
            step="1"
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
     return sliders;
  }
  handleSliderChange(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.value, " ", event.target.id);
    var id = event.target.id;
    var value = event.target.value;
    const slidersWeights = this.state.slidersWeights;
    slidersWeights[id] = parseInt(value);
    var sumOfCustomWeights = 0;
    const slidersLabels = this.state.slidersLabels;
    for (var i = 0; i < slidersLabels.length; i++)
      sumOfCustomWeights += slidersWeights[slidersLabels[i]];
    this.setState({ slidersWeights, sumOfCustomWeights });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SlidersExample />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 18px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}

#app{
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution working perfectly with me ;)

Using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrnqm0k06l)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a class:

```
class Input extends React.Component{

    // render:
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="Input">
                <input type="range" defaultValue="20000" min="0" max="100000" step="5"
                    onChange={(e) => Input.onChange(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    //onChange:
    static onChange(value){
        console.log('value', value);
    }

}
```