# Continuously updated slider can't be dragged

Tags: html, reactjs, range

I'm using React wrapped with cljs+reagent to make a small app. One of the things I need is a slider that updates ~every second, and that can be adjusted by the user. Right now I'm using this:

```
 [:div.scrubber [:input
                 {:type  "range"
                  :min   "0"
                  :max   "100"
                  :value (str percent-through)}]]
```

I'm adjusting the `value` property of the range slider every second. However, this seems to prevent user interaction with it. Here's a gif showing this: (captured on chrome)

[image]

What is the best way to allow the user to control the slider? Stopping the update timer does not have any effect, and it appears that the value is locked.

Comment: This is unwittingly a duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122034/jsx-react-html5-input-slider-doesnt-work`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah if you have control over the timer I would cancel it once the user starts to interact with the slider, and then after updating state with their changes, create a new timer.

Comment: I tried that but to no avail. It appears that something deeper is happening here and that somehow the slider is locked.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm not too familiar with cljs or reagant, can you provide the mechanism for updating value each second? Or is that magically handled in the background somehow?

Comment: You can basically disregard the cljs and reagent part. It's a transpiler language and a thin wrapper over React.js. My mechanism is `setInterval` that calls an event to update the current percent of the input range. However, my problem actually is my use of `value`. I should be using `default-value`. That leads to the problem of the range never updating though...