# HTML input type='range' not moving

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

I have an *Options* component containing a slider input.
I don't understand why the thumb of the slider doesn't move if I set the "value" parameter, but i need it.

Here the code:

```
const Options: React.FC<Props> = () => {

    return (
        <div className='options'>
            <span className='boh'>CUSTOMIZE YOUR PASSWORD</span>
            <div className='slider-container'>
                <input type="range" id="slider" min="1" max="100" value='10' />
                <label htmlFor="slider">Length</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Options
```

I thank anyone who gives me a hand

Comment: You might need to update the value on input change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122034/jsx-react-html5-input-slider-doesnt-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the `value` parameter with `defaultValue`

Answer (score 1):

You set this up in such a way that your value will always be 10. If you want to be able to change that, you'll need to set the state in react to the initial value of 10, and also add the logic to be able to mutate that value. Here's one way to do this:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const [value, changeValue] = useState(10)

return (
<input value={value} onChange={e => changeValue(e.target.value)} />
)
```